# How to iterate through a list so that the last iteration step goes back to the first object?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of points that form a plane. I want to create edges between consecutive points and add them to another list.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
// Get points forming the plate
ArrayList points = part.points;

// Number of points forming the plate
int pointCount = points.Count;

// Create edges
List<LineSegment> edges = new List<LineSegment>();
for (int i = 0; i < pointCount - 1; i++)
{
    // Get start and end points
    Point start = points[i];
    Point end = points[i+1];

    // Create edge
    LineSegment edge = new LineSegment(start, end);

    // Add edge to the list
    edges.Add(edge);
}
```

It doesn't quite work because it doesn't create the last edge between the last and the first points on the list. What would be the way to correct it? I could make it work with an if statement like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
{
    // Get start and end points
    Point start = points[i] as Point;
    Point end;
    if (i == pointCount-1) end = points[0] as Point;
    else end = points[i+1] as Point;

    // Rest of the code here
}
```

But I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it. In Python I would start the loop from -1 so that the first edge would actually be connecting the last point to the first point, but that is not possible in C#.

**EDIT:** The points list is given as an ArrayList by the API.

Comment: Apart from question, use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`. This will give you typed collection.

Comment: Why not keeping the loop as-is, and doing your last step outside of the loop? Should be always the same command, linking between points[0] and points[points.Length-1].

Comment: Not really sure about the downvote, this looks like an ok question

Comment: @Habib I use an ArrayList because that is what I get from the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An 'elegant' solution is using a [modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
{
    …
    // for i+1 == pointCount this will yield points[0]
    Point end = points[(i+1) % pointCount] as Point;
    …
}
```

However, I believe the `if` statement you used is more readable.

Note: Use a `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator (which is ´%´ in C#).

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
{
    // Get start and end points
    Point start = points[i] as Point;
    Point end = points[(i + 1) % pointCount];

    // Rest of the code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would kill all off all the indices and the explicit loops and describe the problem itself, rather than how to solve it.

```
var offsetPoints = points.Skip(1).Concat(new[]{points.First()});

List<LineSegment> edges = 
    points.Zip(offsetPoints, (p1, p2) => new LineSegment(p1, p2)).ToList();
```

I just create an offset list that skips the first element at the start and adds it at the end so the offset list and the original list are the same length.

For illustration, I'd be starting with some sequence:

> {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}

And producing a sequence:

> {p2, p3, p4, p5, p1}

Then I zip them together, creating a line segment from the points that appear at the same position in each sequence.

Continuing with the above example, creating a new sequence from the elements in both using an arbitrary function:

> {f(p1, p2), f(p2, p3), f(p3, p4), f(p4, p5), f(p5, p1)}

where `f` is my supplied zipping function.

This  approach requires far less code and is far less likely to lead to indexing bugs.